# jsf requestscope in list

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I have a simple form in JSF and I want to add the bean associated with this form in an ArrayList.

Here my form :

```
    <h:form styleClass="form-horizontal">
      <div class="row bottom-offset-20">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div>
                <h:outputLabel for="pseudo">pseudo</h:outputLabel>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h:inputText id="pseudo" styleClass="form-control input-lg" value="${storyController.story.author}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h:commandButton action="#{storyController.save}" styleClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="send.story.button"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</h:form>
```

My controller :

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class StoryController implements Serializable {

    private DefaultStoryService defaultStoryService;

    @Inject
    private Story story;

    @Inject
    public StoryController(DefaultStoryService defaultStoryService) {
        this.defaultStoryService = defaultStoryService;
    }

    public String save() {
        defaultStoryService.save(story);

        return "index.xhtml";
    }

    public void setStory(Story story) {
        this.story = story;
    }

    public Story getStory() {
        return story;
    }
}
```

The service :

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class DefaultStoryService {

    @Inject
    StoryMock mock;

    public void save(Story story) {
        mock.addStory(story);
    }
}
```

The ArrayList:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class StoryMock implements Serializable {

    private List<Story> stories;

    @PostConstruct
    public void setupData() {
        stories = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<Story> getStories() {
        return stories;
    }

    public void setStories(List<Story> stories) {
        this.stories = stories;
    }

    public void addStory(Story story) {
        stories.add(story);
    }

}
```

And the story bean:

```
@Model
public class Story implements Serializable {

    private Long id;

    private String author;
}
```

My problem is that when a create a new story and save it, all the stories in the list are updated with the new values.

In my debugger, at the first call :

[first call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsedK.png)

And the second call :

[second call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOP5I.png)

It's like the request scope does not work.
I don't get why the bean is not just add to the list, but it replace all the bean added before.

Answer (score 0):

Please create and assign the Story object in a postconstruct method in controller and do not use @Inject to inject it.

Comment: Why I can't inject the bean? Why I have to manually create thé objectif instead of use DI?

Comment: When you inject the model bean, the bean's lifecycle is managed by the container. In this since there is no scope associated with the bean, when you use inject in the requestscoped controller the chances are that the same bean will be reused again. Thats the reason you are seeing the duplicate values of the same bean in the arraylist. You will have to create the bean whenever you require it.

Comment: If you are particular about using the DI then Story needs to be Dependent scoped, but I dont think scoped annotations on model or entity objevt is recommended or practiced.

Comment: Put `@Model` is not `@Named` + `@RequestScoped` Stereotype?
I tried with `@Named` + `@RequestScoped` and I have the same problem. I don't get why the bean is not alive only during the request.
I tried with `@Named` + `@Dependent` an it works.
If I put a `new Story()` everywhere I need a Story, how I can easily unit tests classes?

I tried with

Comment: If you are planning to have the story in controller and binding it in page, then you can create the story in postconstruct method so that the values are populated  from the page on submit. Will this work your case? But do not inject it. Its not a good and correct pattern and is discouraged.

Comment: Ok, I thought that injected the object was better than created it within the class.
And I should create one Controller per view (facelet) ?

Comment: Yes injecting is better but not for the model object. You can create one controller per view or multiple views depending on your business case. If two views are not related to each other then you can create one controller per view. If two views share considerable fonctionality in common you can use the same controller.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answers. I have a last question, what about pass the story as an argument to the save method and use `#{story.author}` in the view?

Comment: I dont think you can do that because you are calling the save method on submit.

Comment: I tried and it worked. I removed the `Story` property from the `StoryController` and I pass the story like that `action="#{storyController.save(story)}"`. Now I can moke story in my tests. Is it a good practice?